# Accented urls in c# to create xml? (Exception occured while inserting entry)

Tags: c#, xml, urlencode

I am trying to build some xml files with c#, the following is where i do get a problem :

```
      StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder ();

      tmp.Append ("<link>");
      tmp.Append ("<url>").Append (link).Append ("</url>");
      tmp.Append ("<hash>").Append ((link).Content.StringValue.ToUpper ()).Append ("</hash>");
      tmp.Append ("</link>");
```

when the `link` doesn't have some special characters like "é" it works fine, but for a link like "fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Été" i get this error :

`Exception occured while inserting entry: XML parsing: line 1, character 218, illegal xml character`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Accented characters aren't legal in URIs: [tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2)

You should use [System.Uri.EscapeUriString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring.aspx):

```
EscapeUriString((link).Content.StringValue.ToUpper())
```